# CodeIgniter 4: Using Session Variables in Routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, routes, codeigniter-4

I have a project where members can create an account, upload images, subscribe to other members, like/dislike/comment/etc. on images, and view other member profiles.

I am running into an issue where I cannot use session variables in my routes. I am trying to do this by passing parameters to my controllers for logged in user's profile page that is also used for other user's profile page. This use to work before I switched $routes->setAutoRoute(FALSE).

For example: `http://localhost/users/profile/{session(...username')}` and `http://localhost/users/profile/{$otherUser}` would use the same Controllers and Views just different URI segments.

I have read that you cannot use session variables in routes because they are initialized after the routes have already been constructed. Is there anyway around this such as through Events or Hooks? If so how do I implement that? I am fairly new to CodeIgniter 4 and teaching myself PHP as I go (though a little more familiar). So please be kind if this is a stupid question.

Here is some of my code starting with the View '\App\Views\templates\header.php'

```php
<a href='<?= route_to('member_profile', session()->get('username')); ?>' title='My Profile'>My Profile <i class='fas fa-user-edit dropdown-icon' style='color:black'></i></a>

<a href='<?= route_to('member_profile', $row->uploader);?>' title='<?= $row->uploader . "'s Profile"; ?>><?= esc($row->uploader); ?></a>
```

Here is my '\App\Config\Routes.php':

```php
$routes->get('profile/(:segment)', 'Users\Members::profile/$1', ['as' => 'member_profile']);
```

Here is an excerpt of my Controller '\App\Controllers\Users\Members.php:

```php
public function profile(string $user)
    {
        $data = [];

        if (session()->get('username') == $user) {

            $data = [
                'title'        => 'My Profile',
                'editProfile'  => TRUE,
            ];
        
        } else {

            $data = [
                'title'        => $user . "'s Profile",
                'editProfile'  => FALSE,
            ];
        }

        $data['profile'] = $this->profileModel->getUser($user);
        $data['userUploads'] = $this->imageModel->getImagesWhere(['uploader' => $user]);
        $data['userSubscribed'] = $this->subscribeModel->userSubscribed($user);
        $data['script'] = 'js/profile.php';

        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('templates/navigation', $data);
        echo view('users/profile', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

Comment: fetch the session data in the controller and continue from there... you are calling the same controller and method anyway with `http://localhost/users/profile/session_data_like_id_or_similar`

Comment: How would I do that? In my BaseController? @Vickel Sorry I'm confused.

Comment: *I am running into an issue where I cannot use session variables in my routes*: route to controller you want. In the controller's index method (or if in the route any other method defined) you fetch the session data...

Comment: Easiest answer is probably just passing the session data into the view itself; the second parameter of `view()` is a data array that you can then access from inside the view itself. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=view#view

Comment: Can you show me @parttimeturtle?